# As of now, who determines what is canon in the Tolkien universe?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, canon, j-r-r-tolkien

With the debut of “Rings of Power,” I want to know whether the idea of “canon” exists in the Tolkien universe, and if so, who determines canon at this point in time?

Comment: Does an adaptation ever have an effect on "canon"? Tolkien's writings will remain Tolkien's writing, this adaptation will remain this adaptation.

Comment: There really can't be a Middle-Earth canon, since Tolkien himself wrote different versions of many Middle-Earth stories. Christopher Tolkien decided which to put into *The Silmarillion*, but he could have made other choices from the material left behind by his father.

Comment: https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Canon